# Can the use of HTML in questions/answers be a privilege?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, design, privileges

Multiple times now I have seen new users post questions that look like this:

> I have the following:
> ID
> Name
> Something else
>  
>   This is my code:
>
> Some code that's not even formatted

Which is rendered from this:

```
<br>
I have the following:<br><br>ID<br>Name<br>Something else<br>
<br><br>
This is my code:<br><br>

Some code that's not even formatted
```

Can we please make it stop? It's:

- Hard to understand
- Harder to clean up
- Really annoying

Can the use of HTML in posts be made a privilege earned at, say, 100 reputation? This way new users would have to learn Markdown before being allowed to use HTML directly in their posts.

Comment: What is the reason to allow HTML in the first place? I don't really see any significant advantage in allowing users to use HTML and mix it with markdown.

Comment: @MadScientist: I'm not going that far, say we keep it for now, because people hate changes way too much for it to pass like that. But please, just have the newbs learn how to write proper markdown before getting allowed to use HTML.

Comment: @MadScientist Sometimes html is the only way to do certain things; eg emphasis inside words

Comment: Markdown contains all HTML. So what you ask for is technically contradicting itself. ;) (yeah, it's a bit of not answering the question, I know :))

Comment: @hakre: You know what I meant, stop being nitpicky :P Disallow the use of HTML tags for new users. Tis' all.

Comment: Isn't it already restricted to users with at least 10 points?

Comment: @AndersUP: No, it isn't.

Comment: @RichardTingle: And so, you would be able to do so, when you get to 100 (or whatever) reputation, just until you learn how to use proper markdown, then use all the HTML you want.

Comment: I did forget a few things you can't do with Markdown, the `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags are rather useful.

Comment: @MadScientist: Very rarely useful for <100 rep users.

Comment: @MadScientist - Also `<s>` , `<kbd>`

Comment: @hims056: Again, rarely useful for low-rep users. And should be interpolated into markdown as `---text---` like in chat, but that's a different story.

Comment: Ah, no, that's only links.

Comment: One huge argument against this would be that it would make it impossible for low-rep users to edit posts by high-rep users that use HTML.

Comment: it is +2 for editing those <br>'s

Comment: @MadScientist but review mechanism already skips unchanged lines. It wouldn't be hard to allow low-rep users to edit as long as they stay out of HTML. Isn't it similar with images, for example?

Comment: How would this work with questions tagged [HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)? If you leave that open, people will start incorrectly tagging things so their HTML works.

Comment: @thegrinner: Huh? I don't understand the question.

Comment: If a new user has a question where HTML is relevant and uses the HTML tag, can they still post HTML? If so, how do you avoid users adding the HTML tag to any question just to enable HTML in markup?

Comment: @thegrinner: Yes, HTML in code is possible, much like the current privilege allows coded image syntax to be added. You can even add a nice notice about code formatting yaddy yaddy yadda.

Comment: @Mad Scientist: How often does that happen anyway?

Comment: TIL you can use HTML in a post.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree because [html](/questions/tagged/html) is a valid tag. You end up with some ugly options:

1. Restricting new posters from any HTML tag.
2. Prevent new posters from posting relevant HTML.
3. Have new users tagging questions as HTML to get around no longer being able to use HTML without that tag.
4. Only allow HTML in code blocks.

To my mind, the first three of these options are really bad. 1 and 2 suggest new users will have difficulty getting answers when their HTML is necessary to solve the problem (more code in comments? Ew). 3 just adds to the amount of cleanup necessary in these cases (fix the tags *and* the post).

The fourth option is a bit better, but there are plenty of new users who don't understand how to use code block formatting. Those users will have more trouble effectively getting help.

---

**tl;dr:** I don't think the potential reduction in the editing workload is worth either preventing new users from getting some questions answered or increasing the editing workload in some cases.

Comment: That's exactly **the point**, have them learn how to use markdown, before they can use HTML. Also, I'm not speaking about HTML for questions, I'm speaking about HTML for formatting, `<br> <sup> <sub> <s> <code>` etc.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Sure, them knowing how to use the markdown is nice, but I don't see why it should be a barrier to entry - I feel like most of the time I see markdown issues they didn't have code blocks (copy-paste), a list that wasn't properly formatted, included a raw textual link, or posted a link to an image. I don't see a reason for any of those to be barriers to entry. As for limiting it to the formatting subset of HTML, I don't see how that provides enough mitigation here - those could be part of the code in a question. Admittedly it's less likely, but I don't think it's unlikely enough.

Comment: Would it be wrong to put the numbered list above in a code section? ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to disagree with the premise that these posts would be any better if all they had access to was Markdown. I've seen just as many (maybe even more...) questions/answers written by low and moderately high rep users that were jacked up using nothing more than Markdown - or not using any markup at all.

The number of people helped by restricting HTML in questions/answers would be far outweighed by the number of people hindered by the restrictions. There are a number of areas where Markdown just isn't as flexible or holds no alternative - `<kbd>`, `<sub>`, and `<sup>` for example. That's why the mix is there in the first place.

Suggested edits, and 2k+ edit privileges do a lot to help mitigate the problem. We could do more to comment and coach the person on better formatting, though I do have to say I've seen a few that pick up on better formatting after they've had their 3<sup>rd</sup> or 4<sup>th</sup> post edited.